# AVG Bill over Mulitple Dates in Teradata

Tags: aggregate, average, teradata

I need to find an Average Bill of a customer from a certain date to 12 months back. I tried doing Nesting Aggregate but I am getting zero results

Can someone please help ?

Thanks

Comment: What did you try? `SUM(CASE WHEN datecol BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12) AND CURRENT_DATE THEN valcol END`?

Comment: I did try that but since the date I am using is different for all the accounts, and the bill are all based on run_date which is first of every month. I am seeing null results.  But if I can cast the date to the first of the month and then try this syntax, do you think It should work?

Comment: Pobably, `TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM')` returns the 1st of month.